# How to make .filter work in IE8 - polyfill not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, filtering

I am using filtr.js to filter content (http://docs.toddish.co.uk/filtr). Here's the filter part of that script:

```
// Filter the items
        items.filter(function(item) {

            if( o.checkItem.call(p, value, item) ){

                toShow.push(item.item);

            }else{

                toHide.push(item.item);

            }

        });
```

I discovered I need to use this polyfill to make filter work in IE8. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility

However, I must be implementing it incorrectly, because it is doing nothing in IE8. It still throws this error:

"Object doesn't support this property or method." in reference to the items.filter() line.

Here is a fiddle, which shows the Filter.js code, with the addition of the polyfill at the top, plus this initialization code at the end:

http://jsfiddle.net/6gF3s/2/

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: It'd be helpful to know the way in which it "doesn't work". Are there errors in the developer console?

Comment: Wait - your polyfill is for the `.indexOf()` function, not `.filter()`.  IE8 doesn't support `.filter()`.

Comment: No there are no errors once I add the polyfill. Pre-polyfill it gave me the "object not supported" error. But, by "not working" I mean that it's not affecting the content in any way. It is not filtering. It's doing nothing at all.

Comment: Pointy, I know I accidentally posted the wrong fiddle and link. I just updated to the correct links.

Comment: http://docs.toddish.co.uk/filtr/demos/ also not working in **IE8**

Comment: @Pointy actually, it IS still throwing the error with the polfyill. Object doesn't support this property or method. Referring to this line:  items.filter(function(item) {

Comment: @Lindsay hmm .... ok well I'm starting up my IE8 VM.

Comment: Well unfortunately jsfiddle doesn't support IE8 at all, so it's not possible to see what's going on.

Comment: When I visit your demo page in IE8, it does fail, but I can't see any trace of the polyfill either. Are you sure you're really publishing that?

Comment: I added the polyfill. It is not included in the original script. But I can see that it's there when I view firebug lite in IE8.

Comment: I created a jsbin from your fiddle http://jsbin.com/qixog/1 and it works fine in IE8. From the IE8 developer console on your demo page, `Array.prototype.filter` is `undefined`. However you're adding the polyfill on the real page, it's not working.

Comment: Hmm... ok, I see your jsbin working in IE8 as well. But when I put that exact script onto my real site, it still throws the IE8 error. There must be something on my page preventing the polyfill from being recognized? Also, I'm not sure what demo page you're referring to? Do you mean the Filtr.js demo pages? Thank you for your help.